# Trying to retrieve the logged in users information from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get the current logged in users information from my Database. But when I run my code and log in as a trail user account it doesn't show their information but if i log into the user that is at the top of my database it shows their information. Example:

Bigfella account actually gets info from database ex: profile picture, description.
[image: beta]

Beta account gets the profile picture, and description from the bigfella account
[image: betaaccount]

Heres my database table:

[image: USER INFO]

Heres my Code:

```
  <?php 
    include('functions.php');

 if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: login.php');
    }

    require_once 'dbcon.php';

 ?>


        <?php
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT id, username, description, userprofile FROM users ORDER BY id DESC');
    $stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
     $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        extract($row);
}
        ?>
```

HTML for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>  Home</title>
</head>
<body>





            <!-- logged in user information -->
        <div class="profile_info">
            <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['userprofile']; ?>" class="img-rounded" width="250px" height="250px" />
            <div>
                <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) : ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username']; ?></strong>

                    <small>
                        <i  style="color: #888;">(<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['user']['user_type']); ?>)</i> 
                        <br>
                        <a href="home.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a>

                    </small>
<h4> Status: <?php echo $description ?> </h4>

                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?? So its getting only the logged in users information? Thank You In advance!!

Comment: Your code doesn't query the database for information about the user which is logged in.  It gets the row with the maximum id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be able to run a query like this:

$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT id, username, description, userprofile FROM users WHERE id='.$_SESSION['user']['id']);